# AS3: Breakpoints in Intellij Idea do not work for me

Tags: java

I am trying to check how debugging works in IntelliJ idea for AS3. Have set several breakpoints (http://screencast.com/t/wLmLU12RE), but the code do not when I click on debug...

Don't understand what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Debugger console shows 2 possible reasons:

- To check that Flash Player is a debugger one check 'Show redraw regions' item presence in its right click menu.
- To check that SWF is compiled with debugging information check corresponding option at the Compiler Options tab of the Flash build configuration (Project Structure dialog).